# properties to hashmap<String, String>

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

I'm attempting to rewrite all the values in a properties file into a hashmap but when I attempt to run this code

```
for (String keys: properties.entrySet())
    {
        hMap.put(keys,  properties.get(keys));
    }
```

I get the following error.

```
The method put(String, String) in the type Map<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Map.Entry<Object,Object>, Object)
```

I understand that one is a String type and one is a Object but I have no idea how to fix it becuase I'm pretty new to programming...

Comment: Yeah it was a duplicate question... I've been trying to solve this for a while now and that thread helped a lot the larger issue was reading the properties from the file more than turning them into a hashmap.... thank you again and sorry for the repeat....

Answer (score 2):

You get Map.Entry as the return type of Properties.entrySet().

```
for (Map.Entry entry: properties.entrySet(
{
   hMap.put((String)entry.getKey(),  (String)entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
for (String keys: properties.stringPropertyNames())  
{
        hMap.put(keys,  properties.get(keys));
}
```